# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus improper integral question

Tags: integration, derivatives, proof-verification

I want to find the derivative of a function G(x) defined by:

$$ G(t) = \int_{0}^{t^2} x^{2} \sin(x^{2}) \, dx$$

Am I correct in evaluating the answer to be $= 2t^{3}\sin(t^{2})$?

What I did was basically substitute the upper limit into $x^{2}$ and multiplied the whole thing by the derivative of $t^{2}$. Can someone help me understand a general formula on how to calculate problems like these, especially if the upper and lower limits are less straightforward and when the function to be integrated is also more complicated?

Would appreciate any references to resources! Thank you very much and cheers!

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function $$F(x) = \int x^2\sin (x^2) dx$$

Then, by the Newton-Leibniz formula $$G(t) = \int_{0}^{t^2} x^{2} \cdot \sin(x^{2}) \cdot dx = F(t^2) - F(0)$$

Now, seeing that $F(0)$ is a constant, the derivative of $G(t)$ is given by
$$G'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F(t^2)$$

From the definition of $F(x)$ it follows that $F'(t)=t^2\sin t^2$, and hence $$\frac{d}{dt}F(t^2) = \frac{dF(t^2)}{d(t^2)} \cdot \frac{d(t^2)}{dt}$$

We conclude that $G'(t) = 2t^5 \sin (t^4)$.

Comment: This is not correct. You must use the chain rule to differentiate $F(t^2)$

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I noticed. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not the right way to do it.

Consider instead
$$
F(t)=\int_0^t x^2\sin(x^2)\,dx
$$
Then you can write $G(t)=F(t^2)$, so
$$
G'(t)=2tF'(t^2)
$$
by the chain rule. Since $F'(t)=t^2\sin(t^2)$, you have
$$
G'(t)=2t\cdot t^4\sin(t^4)=2t^5\sin(t^4)
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

IMHO, I would suggest to simply remember that the fundamental theorem of calculus write
$$g(x)=\frac d {dx} \, \int_a^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)$$